# Unable to debug a function in R

Tags: r, oracle, debugging

Debugging the R script I have come across a strange error: “Error in debug(fun, text, condition) : argument must be a closure”. 
PC features: Win7/64 bit, Oracle client 12 (both 32 and 64bit), R (64bit)

Earlier the script has been debugged well without errors. I have looked for a clue in the Inet but have found no clear explanation what the mistake is and how to remove it. 
Running the script as a plain script but not a function produces no errors.

I would be very grateful for your ideas 

The source script (connection to oracle DB and executing a simple query)as follows (conects to Oracle DB and execute the query:

```
download1<-function(){
if (require("dplyr")){
#install.packages("dplyr")
}
if (require("RODBC")){
#install.packages("RODBC")
}

library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)

# to establish connection with DB or schema
con <- odbcConnect("DB", uid="ANALYTICS", pwd="122334fgcx", rows_at_time = 500,believeNRows=FALSE)

# Check that connection is working (Optional)
odbcGetInfo(con)

# Query the database and put the results into the data frame "dataframe"
ptm <- proc.time()
x<-sqlQuery(con, "select *  from my_table") 
proc.time()-ptm


# to extract all field names to the separate vector 
#field_names<-sqlQuery(con,"SELECT column_name FROM   all_tab_cols WHERE    table_name = 'MY_TABLE'")

close(con)
}

debug(download1(),text = "", condition = NULL)
```

Comment: @vck is right, you  need to write 'debug(download1)' instead of debug(download1()). The reason is that you want to pass the function object to the method (which is done with function call parantheses) instead of the return value of the function. In your code download1() is executed and then the return value (which it does not have) is passed to the method debug. More on debugging: http://blog.haunschmid.name/debugging-in-r/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
debug(download1)
download1()
```

Comment: thank a lot. It seems to me I appeared to be overloaded with coding :-) everything looks pretty straightforward.